# Cox hazard Model: HR of 1 variable greater than 1 in simple regression becomes smaller than 1 in a multiple regression

Tags: survival, cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

I'm performing a simple and multiple Cox regression. I have 1 dependent variable
$y$ and 10 independent variables:

$$X = x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8, x_9, x_{10}$$

A particularity of the model is that

$${x_8}_i + {x_9}_i = {x_{10}}_i$$

(i.e. that the vector $x_{10}$ is the addition of $x_8$ and $x_9$)

When running the *simple* Cox regression model

- $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$, $x_6$, $x_7$ are not survival predictors (i.e. their HR are cross 1 and are of the type HR: 1.1, 95% CI: [0.8-1.2}, p > 0.05)
- whereas $x_8$, $x_9$, $x_{10}$ are predictor of **poorer** (i.e. their HR are above 1 and are of the type HR: 1.2, 95% CI: [1.1-2.0}, p < 0.05)

When running the *multiple* Cox regression model

- $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$, $x_6$, $x_7$ are still not survival predictors
- $x_8$, $x_9$, $x_{10}$ are still predictor of **poorer** (i.e. their HR are above 1 and are of the type HR: 1.2, 95% CI: [1.1-2.0}, p < 0.05)
- whereas $x_{10}$ are predictor of **better** (i.e. their HR are under 1 and are of the type HR: 0.8, 95% CI: [0.6-0.9}, p < 0.05)

Here are my questions:

1. Is it ok to use a variable such $x_{10}$ which is a linear combination of other 2 explanatory variables (in this case $x_8$ and $x_9$)
2. How come $x_{10}$ which is statistically significant predictor of **poorer** survival in the simple model becomes a significant predictor of **better** survival in the multiple model (instead of simply becoming a non significant predictor of poorer survival). Does it have to do with the fact that it is a linear combination of $x_8$ and $x_9$

Comment: For the point 1, I would not use linearly dependent variables in a linear model. For the second point, it is normal, read about confounding.

Comment: thank you for your comment @marc1s. Regarding the point 2, do you have a link that talks about that precise behaviour?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding